# Help in solving high-dimensional definite integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to solve a 6D integral over this integrated

```
integrand=ConditionalExpression[(9*(1 + E^(R*\[Eta]1))^2*(1 +E^(R*\[Eta]2))^2*R^6*(\[Eta]1 - \[Xi]1)*(\[Eta]1 + \[Xi]1)*(\[Eta]2 - \[Xi]2)*(\[Eta]2 + \[Xi]2))/(E^(R*(-2 + \[Eta]1 + \[Eta]2 + \[Xi]1 + \[Xi]2))*(128*Pi^2*(3 + 3*E^R + R*(3 + R))^2*Sqrt[R^2*(-2 + \[Eta]1^2 + \[Eta]2^2 + \[Xi]1^2 - 2*\[Eta]1*\[Eta]2*\[Xi]1*\[Xi]2 + \[Xi]2^2 - 2*Sqrt[-((-1 + \[Eta]1^2)*(-1 + \[Xi]1^2))]*Sqrt[-((-1 + \[Eta]2^2)*(-1 + \[Xi]2^2))]*Cos[\[Phi]1 - \[Phi]2])])), Re[R] > 0]

Vee = Integrate[integrand, {\[Xi]1, 1, \[Infinity]}, {\[Eta]1, -1, 1}, {\[Phi]1, 0, 2*\[Pi]}, {\[Xi]2, 1, \[Infinity]}, {\[Eta]2, -1, 1}, {\[Phi]2, 0, 2*\[Pi]}]
```

with the limits $\xi_1,\xi_2$ from 1 to $\infty$, $\eta_1$,$\eta_2$ from -1 to 1 and $\phi_1,\phi_2$ from 0 to $2\pi$. By the way, this is calculating the electrostatic energy of the H$_2$ molecule in confocal, elliptic coordinates. The problem is, this integral is running for a long time and does not finish. I am not sure if it is working properly or not, since there is no response, it just keeps running. Any idea how to solve or speed up this integral?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as copyable *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: I tried to follow the procedure. Is it better now?

Comment: yes, thanks. Not sure whether it will be easy for someone to help or not.  If the conditional expression is meant to add an assumption that `Re[R] > 0`, the typical way to do that is adding the option `Assumptions -> Re[R] > 0` to `Integrate`.

Comment: I will try that, definitely R is a real number and larger than 0

Comment: "R is a real number and larger than 0" -- then use `Assumptions -> R > 0`. Variables that appear in inequalities are assumed to be real.  `Re[R] > 0` signals that `R` is complex, with a positive real part.  (Integrate[] still seems to run forever, though.)

Comment: Yeah, it seems to not help much, quite high dimensional integral. Would it help to solve this numerically instead? Of course I would love to have an analytic solution, but if it is not possible, I guess I would just to with the numeric solution.

Comment: The expression pasted into Mathematica runs forever.  1.  write the pure integand and try integration over one angle. If that doesnt produce an EllipticF, stop. 2. Mathematica has no implementation for multidimensional definite integrals but somebody has written a dysfunctional algorithm, Since most users let the system have access to the internet, this is only an error collector for some AI basis: Integrate typically starts a pattern recognition process that is known to not terminate on random input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can reduce dimension from 6 to 4 using

```
 Integrate[
 1/Sqrt[a Cos[p1 - p2] + b], {p1, 0, 2 Pi}, {p2, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]

(*Out[1]= (8 \[Pi] EllipticK[(2 a)/(a + b)])/Sqrt[a + b] *)
 % /. {a -> -2*Sqrt[-((\[Eta]1^2 - 1)*(\[Xi]1^2 - 1))]*Sqrt[-((\[Eta]2^2 - 1)*(\[Xi]2^2 - 1))], b -> \[Eta]1^2 - 2*\[Eta]1*\[Eta]2*\[Xi]1*\[Xi]2 + \[Eta]2^2 + \[Xi]1^2 + \[Xi]2^2 - 2}

(*Out[2]= (8 \[Pi] EllipticK[-((
   4 Sqrt[-((-1 + \[Eta]1^2) (-1 + \[Xi]1^2))]
     Sqrt[-((-1 + \[Eta]2^2) (-1 + \[Xi]2^2))])/(-2 + \[Eta]1^2 + \
\[Eta]2^2 + \[Xi]1^2 - 2 \[Eta]1 \[Eta]2 \[Xi]1 \[Xi]2 + \[Xi]2^2 - 
    2 Sqrt[-((-1 + \[Eta]1^2) (-1 + \[Xi]1^2))]
      Sqrt[-((-1 + \[Eta]2^2) (-1 + \[Xi]2^2))]))])/Sqrt[-2 + \
\[Eta]1^2 + \[Eta]2^2 + \[Xi]1^2 - 
 2 \[Eta]1 \[Eta]2 \[Xi]1 \[Xi]2 + \[Xi]2^2 - 
 2 Sqrt[-((-1 + \[Eta]1^2) (-1 + \[Xi]1^2))]
   Sqrt[-((-1 + \[Eta]2^2) (-1 + \[Xi]2^2))]]*)
```

Therefore integral can be evaluated in 4 dimensional space as follows

```
f[R_?NumericQ] := (9*R^5)/(128*
     Pi^2*(R*(R + 3) + 3*E^R + 
        3)^2) NIntegrate[(8*(1 + E^(R*\[Eta]1))^2*(1 + 
         E^(R*\[Eta]2))^2*
      Pi*(\[Eta]1 - \[Xi]1)*(\[Eta]1 + \[Xi]1)*(\[Eta]2 - \[Xi]2)*(\
\[Eta]2 + \[Xi]2)*
      EllipticK[-((4*Sqrt[-((-1 + \[Eta]1^2)*(-1 + \[Xi]1^2))]*
            Sqrt[-((-1 + \[Eta]2^2)*(-1 + \[Xi]2^2))])/(-2 + \
\[Eta]1^2 + \[Eta]2^2 + \[Xi]1^2 - 
            2*\[Eta]1*\[Eta]2*\[Xi]1*\[Xi]2 + \[Xi]2^2 - 
            2*Sqrt[-((-1 + \[Eta]1^2)*(-1 + \[Xi]1^2))]*
             Sqrt[-((-1 + \[Eta]2^2)*(-1 + \[Xi]2^2))]))])/(E^(R*(-2 \
+ \[Eta]1 + \[Eta]2 + \[Xi]1 + \[Xi]2))*
      Sqrt[-2 + \[Eta]1^2 + \[Eta]2^2 + \[Xi]1^2 - 
        2*\[Eta]1*\[Eta]2*\[Xi]1*\[Xi]2 + \[Xi]2^2 - 
        2*Sqrt[-((-1 + \[Eta]1^2)*(-1 + \[Xi]1^2))]*
         Sqrt[-((-1 + \[Eta]2^2)*(-1 + \[Xi]2^2))]]), {\[Xi]1, 1, 
    Infinity}, {\[Eta]1, -1, 1}, {\[Xi]2, 1, Infinity}, {\[Eta]2, -1, 
    1}, Method -> "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo"];
```

Example of usage

```
f[1] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[]= {0.412131, 0.588934}
```

Also this integral can be computed in 6D as follows

```
integrand = (9*R^6*(\[Eta]1 - \[Xi]1)*(\[Eta]1 + \[Xi]1)*(\[Eta]2 - \[Xi]2)*(\[Eta]2 + \[Xi]2)*(E^(\[Eta]1*R) + 1)^2*
     (E^(\[Eta]2*R) + 1)^2)/(E^(R*(\[Eta]1 + \[Eta]2 + \[Xi]1 + \[Xi]2 - 2))*(128*Pi^2*(R*(R + 3) + 3*E^R + 3)^2*
      Sqrt[R^2*(-(2*Sqrt[-((\[Eta]1^2 - 1)*(\[Xi]1^2 - 1))]*Sqrt[-((\[Eta]2^2 - 1)*(\[Xi]2^2 - 1))]*
           Cos[\[Phi]1 - \[Phi]2]) + \[Eta]1^2 - 2*\[Eta]1*\[Eta]2*\[Xi]1*\[Xi]2 + \[Eta]2^2 + \[Xi]1^2 + \[Xi]2^2 - 2)])); 
lst = Table[{x, 
   NIntegrate[
    integrand /. R -> x, {\[Xi]1, 1, Infinity}, {\[Eta]1, -1, 
     1}, {\[Phi]1, 0, 2*Pi}, {\[Xi]2, 1, Infinity}, {\[Eta]2, -1, 
     1}, {\[Phi]2, 0, 2*Pi}, 
    Method -> "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo"]}, {x, 1/10, 5, 1/10}]
```

Visualization

```
ListPlot[{lst, {{1, f[1]}}}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"R", "Vee"}, PlotLegends -> {"6D", "4D"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Yeah I guess numerical integration is better in this case. I was hoping for an analytic solution, but Mathematica seems not to be able to give it to me.

Comment: @Guiste Yes, you are right. Analytical expression in this case maybe is not so useful. Even reduced from 6D in 4D looks very cumbersome.